# Mootools.floor submitByAjax example?

Tags: ajax, mootools

Does anyone know a way to to Ajax submit with  this
http://mootools.floor.ch/en/labs/index.htm

I see in the script itself it has the option to do so but once I set it to true I am not getting any response and form does not send. I tried to google the ajax example for this script but could not find an example.

Answer (score 0):

Fund a nice reference 
http://maurizio-franco.blogspot.com/2011/09/mootools-formcheck-ajax-configuration.html